# Trying to have a view & block have access to a variable from a another block that is used to determine which element number in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am newer to rails: My side navigation partial takes each step and provides an icon and a link for it.   I would like for the current active step, to have the same icon in the top navigation as the side navigation.  However, <%= icon[i] %> will not work since [i] comes from a different block in a different view.   How would I make it so that the active link top's navigation has the same icon[i] as the side navigation without having access to i? See below.

_side_navigation.html.erb

```
  <% icon= ["icon-link", "icon-bar-chart", "icon-edit", "icon-beaker","icon-link", "icon-bar-chart", "icon-edit", "icon-beaker"] %>


    <% @step_list.each_with_index do |step, i| %>

    <% case step.media_type %>
    <% when 'video' %>
            <li class="<%= nav_active step %>">
              <a href = "
                  <i class='icon-info-sign icon-2x'></i>
                  <span>Video</span>
                </a>
            </li>


    <% when 'excel' %>
            <li class="<%= nav_active step %>">
                  <i class="<%= icon[i] %> icon-2x"></i> **<<I need this [i] in the other partial so I know which element of the array is chosen**
                  <span>Step <%= i %> </span>
              </a>
            </li>

    <% else %>
            <li class="<%= nav_active step %>">
                  <i class="<%= icon[i] %> icon-2x"></i>
                  <span>Step <%= i %></span>
              </a>
            </li>

    <% end %>   
  <% end %>
```

_top_navigation.html.erb

```
<div class="area-top clearfix">
        <div class="pull-left header">


              <% case @step.media_type %>
              <% when 'video' %>
                <h3 class="title">
                  <i class="<%= icon[i] %>"></i></i> <<<here is the problem since, it does not have access to the current "i" from the other block
                  Video
                </h3>
                <h5>
                  A video for the course is here
                </h5>

              <% when 'excel' %>
               <h3 class="title">
                <i class="<%= icon[i] %>"></i></i>
              Excel
            </h3>
            <h5>
              Please use the excel sheet below to complete the challenge.
            </h5>

         <% else %>
           <h3 class="title">
            <i class="<%= icon[i] %>"></i></i>
              Multiple Choice                              
            </h3>
            <h5>
              Please choose from a selection below
            </h5>

         <% end %>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am newer to rails, I feel like this is a hack way of doing it but nonetheless works.  I created the method below, which essentially takes in the step, and if it is the active step, save the current index to a variable.  There is a method within that, which returns the variable while not requiring any inputs (so as to be able to be used freely)

```
   def nav_active_icon(step, i)
    @x = i if params[:id].to_s == step.id.to_s
     def display
       return @x
     end
   end
```

At the bottom, it takes in the step and the index for the method above

```
 <% @step_list.each_with_index do |step, i| %>

     <% case step.media_type %>
     <% when 'video' %>
           <li class="<%= nav_active step %>">
             <span class="glow"></span>
             <a href = "
             <%= course_level_step_path(@course.id, @level.id, step.id) %>" >
                <i class='icon-info-sign icon-2x'></i>
                <span>Video</span>
              </a>
          </li>

          <% nav_active_icon(step, i) %>
```

Here it outputs the current index for the active step in display (in a different view from the block)

```
  <% when 'excel' %>
           <h3 class="title">
            <i class="<%= icons[display] %>"></i></i>
              Excel
            </h3>
            <h5>
              Please use the excel sheet below to complete the challenge.
            </h5>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there no natural order to these steps? You don't have an 'i' you can pass in when you include the partial ([partial local variables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials))?

If not, it sounds like you need a slightly smarter 'Step' object that is aware of its index in the workflow.

You could also place the icon list in a helper, like so:

```
def icons
  ["icon-link", "icon-bar-chart", "icon-edit",
   "icon-beaker","icon-link", "icon-bar-chart",
   "icon-edit", "icon-beaker"]
end
```

Gets it out of your view.

Comment: The problem I am having is that @ step_list is a list of the steps whereas @ step is just hte current step.  so the each_with_index wouldn't correlate for i.  What I am trying to figure out is for the current step what is index [i] of the other block (step_list)

Comment: Your second partial shows this: <% @step.each do |step| %>.  Is that a typo?  The second partial looks like it's doing the exact same thing as the first, just without the index.

Comment: Sorry two different variables but did not explictitly make that clear- one is @ step_list (list of steps for navigation) and one is @ step (current step).  I should not have put the .each do |step| in the second view I guess.  I edited it so the block is gone and the second view just has a case statement.

Comment: There is no natural order to the steps. I found what seems to be a hack way of doing it, which I posted. I appreciate your help.